# Kivy to Apk in Windows

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm using windows right now and I want to ask is there any good tools to package a kivy app for android in windows or do I have to use Linux distributions?

And also is there anyway to use kivy for python 3.3.2 (Latest)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> I'm using windows right now and I want to ask is there any good tools to package a kivy app for android in windows or I have t use Linux distributions?

Unfortunately the build tools don't work on windows right now. I think there are technical barriers to do with cross compilation.

Have you seen the kivy virtual machine, available at http://kivy.org/#download ? This is an Ubuntu linux image that already has the tools installed and set up. You should be able to run it in virtualbox on any recentish machine.

There's also an online interface to the android component of the [buildozer](https://github.com/kivy/buildozer) tool (which can manage the entire android or ios build process, but I think doesn't work on windows at the moment), available at http://android.kivy.org/ . You can upload your project there to have the apk built. I haven't tried this service, but it should work.

> And also is there anyway to use kivy for python 3.3.2?

The next release of kivy will support python 3, and the github master branch at https://github.com/kivy/kivy should be mostly (if not all) working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Kivy launcher now :)

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/packaging-android.html

unfortunately i'm stuck with an issue right now on one of my app.

Answer (score -1):

Use Google Collab. Open [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/kaustubhgupta/0d06ea84760f65888a2488bac9922c25/kivyapp-to-apk.ipynb) and upload your code (press the folder in the left toolbar and press the upload button) and click the play button on every code block one by one.