# How to convert kivy applications (.py) into apk on windows?

Tags: python, module, apk, kivy, buildozer

Note: Before you state that this question is duplicate, and link other questions such as:

[Kivy standalone android apk on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244983/kivy-standalone-android-apk-on-windows)

[Kivy to Apk in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19735768/kivy-to-apk-in-windows)

Keep in mind that they are from 2013-2014, aka 3-4 years ago, I searched around and I could not find any recent questions about this topic.

So I have this windows 10 computer, I have to convert an application made in kivy to apk, I've read the above answers and other resources and found out it is hopeless, and my best bet is to download a virtual machine, but that would take a lot of time just downloading it as my connection speed is pretty slow, so I would rather not take that approach unless it is really the only way to proceed, but all of this information was like 3 years old, is there any recent way to convert kivy to apk on windows without using virtual box and friends?

Note: I'm using Python 2.7.10 atm

Comment: Sorry for posting a link, but maybe this video tutorial could help you: [How to build android apk using Python/Kivy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TCWC4kWOoiI)

Answer (score 0):

python-for-android apparently works in the windows subsystem for linux, available in windows 10, so you could try that. I don't know what issues you might hit in particular. It isn't officially supported, although it probably could be if developers able to test it are interested.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Collab. Open [this link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/kaustubhgupta/0d06ea84760f65888a2488bac9922c25/kivyapp-to-apk.ipynb) and upload your code (press the folder in the left toolbar and press the upload button) and click the play button on every code block one by one.